# Using Intellij Community Edition, getting compile error "java: package javax.servlet.http does not exist"

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Community Edition to build a simple Maven project web app. It's getting compile errors:

> java: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
>
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol: class HttpServlet
>
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse

I used to use Jave SE. I have downloaded Jave EE. All it told me to do was unzip (I guess that means it's installed). I'm also using Tomcat 6.0.53 and Maven 3.5.0

Other similar questions on here said to add dependencies but they did not work for me.

My code is attached:

```
package org.mycompany.myname;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException
{
    httpServletResponse.getWriter().print("Test running ...");
}
}
```

Comment: Wrong all around.   Has nothing to do with IntelliJ.  You should not unzip anything.  You just need to add the javax.servlet JAR to your CLASSPATH when you compile.  Tomcat will have it in its /lib folder when you run.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The version I designated for Java EE in the pom.xml was wrong.